# OnValidating Event in a custom control

Tags: c#, validation

When does the `OnValidate` event fire in the life-cycle of a control?

I'm creating a `DateBox` that will allow the user to enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format (text) and need to verify that the date is in that format. It'll never be converted to a date (stored as string) but I would like to know the best time to validate that data (and provide feedback).

Note: It may seem a bit like re-inventing the wheel, but the app that I'm writing gets deployed to a tablet-pc and the winforms `DateTimePicker` is hell to edit with a stylus and my users just want to be able to write in the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MaskedTextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) might help you.

Comment: You sir, are helpful :) Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

OnValidate happens after the Loading events ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx))

You should validate on the client-side (javascript) **AND** server side either using the OnValidate or when handling the submission of the form (or both).